# jQuery find method ignoring some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somehow jquery find is not returning all matching elements having data-role attribute.

```
 var html = '<html><head></head><body><div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">      </div>          <div data-role="content">      <ul id="pageList" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="false">             <li id="testId"></li>        </ul>    </div></body></html>'
 $(html).find("[data-role]")
```

above code returns only element with id pageList. any idea what is missing?
Copy/paste above code as-is on chrome debugger to see the issue, if you have jquery loaded on current page this should execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

Browser removes your `html` and `body` elements so the top-most elements in the returned jQuery collection are children of the `body` element. As `find` selects the *descendant* elements of the set, the wrapper elements in the set are not included in the new jQuery collection.

You can wrap the html with another element and then use the `find` method:

```
$('<div/>').html(html).find("[data-role]");
```

Comment: Thanks, that at least answers why this was happening! BTW I used this finally : `a = new DOMParser();
b = a.parseFromString(html,"text/html");
$(b).find("[data-role=content]")`